# Extract byte[] from Tap (TapGestureRecognizer) Event to Click Event in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-sqlite

I have struggled with this issue for the past 3 hours and I'd like to ask you support with this matter:
I have a Tap event (image display), which works fine, but i want to add image (base64 string) with other properties to SQLite database using a button (Click event). How can I achieve this?
Here are my codes:

**XAML**

```
<Image x:Name="image" 
       Source="camera2.png" />
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Next" 
            Clicked="Insert" 
            x:Name="BtnInsert"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**TAP EVENT:**

```
 var tapImage = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapImage.Tapped += tapImage_Tapped;
            image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapImage);
 private async void tapImage_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
          file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
          file.Dispose();
          byte[] img = memoryStream.ToArray();
          memoryStream.Dispose();
      }

 }
```

**CLICK EVENT**

```
private void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var options = new InformationTable
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Quantity = TxtQuantity.Text,
        Issue = Ccheck.Checked.ToString(),
        Info = TxtInfo.Text,
        image = Convert.ToBase64String(img),
    };
    _connection.Insert(options);
}
```

My problem is on argument **image**, as I cannot pass argument **byte[] img** from **tap event** to **Insert click event** as described above.

Anyone who can help me?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Maybe I can't understand what you've described due my bad english, but I can't see where you link the tap event with the `image`... and really you can't "pass" arguments between events. You can do it only with methods... Despite this, what if you store the byte[] img into a local variable in the code behind and get this in the clicked event?

Comment: Hi Diego (by your name I asume you a either portuguese or Brazilian (like me), well this is my problem I would like to to pass arguments between events, but I can see it is not possible. Can you show me your idea about the local variable please?  Thanks anyway

Comment: Sure! You have the xaml page and the code behind of it (YourPage.xaml.cs), where you've coded this events, probably. So you can just declare one byte[] variable like `byte[] img = null;` in your `YourPage` class, set the value you got on the tap event and getting it on the 'clicked' event.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not working

Comment: Please, edit your question: omit the code that is not part of the problem context and add the missing ones, so I'll be able to write a tested code that solves it =).

Comment: There's a lot of unusefull information there.

Comment: Hi Diego, I've cleaned it up, in order to clarify my question.  i only want to pass the byte[] argument from the Tap Event to the Insert Click event, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this way:

**Code behind of your XAML page:**

```
byte[] img = null;

var tapImage = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapImage.Tapped += tapImage_Tapped;
image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapImage);
private async void tapImage_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
        file.Dispose();
        img = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Dispose();
    }
}


private void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(img != null)
    {
        var options = new InformationTable
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Quantity = TxtQuantity.Text,
            Issue = Ccheck.Checked.ToString(),
            Info = TxtInfo.Text,
            image = Convert.ToBase64String(img),
        };
        _connection.Insert(options);
    }
}
```